# Reduced relative clauses used with some particular adjectives

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

According to Practical English Usage by Michael Swan,

> Reduced structures are also used with the adjectives **available** and **possible**.

- Please send me all the tickets available. (=...that are available)
- Tuesday’s the only date possible.

However, I came across two examples using reduced structures with **typical**

> - Castle café in the walls serves food **typical** of the castle’s history.
> - Staff wear clothes **typical** of the time, [...]

Why isn’t **typical** included in the given adjectives in the book? Is it another grammar point?

Comment: I wouldn't say that "available" and "possible" are reduced clauses. They are simply adjectives in postpositive position.

Comment: "Please send me all the tickets typical" is not grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use typical in a reduced structure like that, but unlike "available", it would seem to need a phrase "typical of ...."

I don't know why typical isn't included,  probably the list is intended to be illustrative and not exhaustive.